# Prolog: list of n of n x n matrix

Tags: list, matrix, prolog

How to create n x n matrix in Prolog and inside the matrix is list of n to 1.
I can create the coding for generate list but do not know how to create a matrix n x n:

```
make_num_list(N, List) :-
   make_list(N, List).

make_list(N, []) :-
   N =< 0,
   !.
make_list(N, [N|Rest]) :-
   N > 0,
   N2 is N - 1,
   make_list(N2, Rest).
```

Comment: There is no "matrix" data type in Prolog, so we often resort to using a list of lists (where these correspond to rows of the matrix).  With patience and concentration it is possible to implement matrix arithmetic for such a representation.

Answer (score 1):

Reuse your code, and your ideas.

```
make_num_matrix(N, Matrix) :-
    make_matrix(N, N, Matrix).

make_matrix(_, N, []) :-
    N =< 0,
    !.
make_matrix(M, N, [R|Rs]) :-
    make_list(M, R),
    N2 is N - 1,
    make_matrix(M, N2, Rs).

make_list(N, []) :-
    N =< 0,
    !.
make_list(N, [N|Rest]) :-
    N > 0,
    N2 is N - 1,
    make_list(N2, Rest).
```

---

```
?- make_num_matrix(4, M).
M = [[4, 3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1]].
```

Answer (score 1):

most Prolog out there have [between](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=between/3)/3, and surely will have [findall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3)/3

```
make_matrix(N, M) :- findall(Ns, (between(1,N,_), make_list(N,Ns)), M).
```

Comment: @mat: you mean make_matrix/2, I think. But after then we need to maplist... I think learning about findall is (more) fundamental for a newbie...

Comment: @mat: I don't get it... make_list/2 is OP original code. I had to use make_num_list instead...